# Javascript MIME type mismatch error after server move

Tags: error, javascript, migration

I have moved the installed civicrm with Drupal from windows PC to Linux PC and changed the civicrm settings file. Everything working fine but only the javascript files are not loading.

> The resource from
>   “http://localhost/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/modules/templates/CRM/Member/Form/MembershipStandalone.js?os8oog”
>   was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff).

I went to the folder paths files are exist. How to overcome this issue

Comment: did you try https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link but I couldn't find any clue using the link for this MIME error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location) header is a security measure that prevents the browser from attempting to detect the MIME type of a download automatically, as this behavior can be exploited for certain kinds of attacks. The browser will block requests for stylesheets and scripts which are not delivered with a CSS or Javascript MIME type, respectively.

In practice, this means the web server is unable to load the resource for any of several reasons:

- The resource is missing
- The file permissions on the resource prevent it from being loaded by the web server
- The web server is not configured to deliver .js files using a Javascript MIME type

Please confirm that the file exists, that you have followed all the instructions for [moving an existing installation](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location), and that your server is configured correctly, including file permissions and Javascript MIME types. In particular, since this file is loaded in a custom template, you should confirm that the path has not changed.

Comment: You are correct the resource is missing; I opened the URL in chromium browser it shows 404 error; I had a typo error in settings file. It caused to produce the URL like "modules/civicrm/modules" as in my question; but the actual path is 'modules/civicrm/"